# String overlapping when a struct

Tags: c

I write a code to enter student information as follows. The problem occurs when the student ID append Lastname.I know that the error lies in entering id and Lastname but I can not understand and fix it

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
typedef struct Fullname_s{
    char Lastname[20];
    char Fistname[10];
}Fullname;
typedef struct Birthday_s{
    int Day,Month,Year;
}Birthday;
typedef struct Mark_s{
    float mark[10];
}Mark;
typedef struct SV{
    char   ID[8];
    Fullname F_name;
    Birthday B_day;
    char   Sex[5];
    Mark _Mark;
}sv;
sv s[100];
void inputsv(sv s[],int *n); 
void printinfo(int i);
void output(sv s[],int n);
int main(){
    int n;
    inputsv(s,&n);
    output(s,n);
}

void inputsv(sv s[],int *n){
    printf("--------Enter Students information--------\n");
    printf("Enter number of students \n");
    scanf("%d",n);
    int i=0;
    while(i<*n){
        int x;
        printf("-------------------------Student %d-------------------------- \n",i+1);
        printf("ID Student   : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",&s[i].ID);
        gets();
        printf(" Lastname    : ");
        fgets(s[i].F_name.Lastname,20,stdin);
        printf(" Fistname    : ");
        gets(s[i].F_name.Fistname);       
        do{
            puts("Enter 0 :MALE");
            puts("Enter 1 :FEMALE");
            scanf("%d",&x);
            if(x==0)
                strcpy(s[i].Sex,"MALE");
            else
                strcpy(s[i].Sex,"FEMALE");
        }while(x!=0&&x!=1);
        printf(" Birthday    : ");
        scanf("%d%d%d",&s[i].B_day.Day,&s[i].B_day.Month,&s[i].B_day.Year);
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        printf(" Mark %2d:",j+1);
        scanf("%f",&s[i]._Mark.mark[j]);
        }
        i++;
        gets();
    }
}

void output(sv s[],int n){
    printf("STUDENTS INFORMATION \n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("--------------------\n");
        printf("  STUDENT %2d\n",i+1);
        printinfo(i);
        printf("-------------\n");
        }
    printf("------------------------\n");
} 

void printinfo(int i){
    printf(" ID STUDENT  :%s\n",s[i].ID);
    printf(" FULLNAME    :%s %s     \n",s[i].F_name.Lastname,s[i].F_name.Fistname);
    printf(" BIRTHDAY    :%2d-%2d-%4d \n",s[i].B_day.Day,s[i].B_day.Month,s[i].B_day.Year);
    printf(" SEX         :%s\n",s[i].Sex);
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        printf(" MARK    %2d  : %0.2f \n",j+1,s[i]._Mark.mark[j]);
    }
}
```

Error as in the picture.Thanks all
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THxZP.jpg)

Comment: Don't `fflush(stdin)`. `Sex[5]` won't contain `female`. Are you designing for males only? How long is the maximum ID number?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem lies in id and lastname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `s[i].ID` is defined as `char   ID[8]`. Howevr, the ID as input is **1234567b** which is 8 characters. If the id was supposed to be `1234567`, then you neglected to put in the `\0` NULL character that is required to end the string. As a result  `printf(" ID STUDENT  :%s\n",s[i].ID);` prints from the start of `s[i].ID` until the first NULL charater (at the end of the name).

Comment: thank you. So if i want the id to be an 8 character string i must use char id [9]?

Comment: @Divide Of course. Any C tutorial should explain that you need an extra byte in C strings for the trailing null.

Comment: Thank you very much